# Using sed with a variable:

Tags: sed, scripting

So I am using sed to find and replace certain strings:

Case 1. A value in the file is always constant. And I want to replace the parameter from false to true. So I use this command:

```
    sed -i -e 's/entry key="ignore_vc_cert" value="false"/entry key="ignore_vc_cert" value="true"/g'  /usr/local/avamar/var/mc/server_data/prefs/mcserver.xml
```

This will find `ignore_vc_cert` and change its value from `false` to `true`. 
Works good.

Next,I have another file which has the following parameter:

```
<numberOfDisk>4</numberOfDisk>
```

Now, this value here can change depending on deployment. I want to replace the number here, `4`, or whatever with the output of `df -h | grep data0* | wc -l`

So if output of `df -h | grep data0* | wc -l` is `3` it should replace the value for `numberOfDisk` Parameter from `4` to `3`

I wrote this command:

```
sed -e s/"$(cat /usr/local/vdr/etc/vdr-configuration.xml  | grep -i numberOfDisk)"/<numberOfDisk>"$(df -h | grep data0* | wc -l)"</numberOfDisk>/g > /usr/local/vdr/etc/vdr-configuration.xml
```

But form some reason, I get `numberOfDisk: No such file or directory`

If I do:

```
sed -e 's/"$(cat /usr/local/vdr/etc/vdr-configuration.xml  | grep -i numberofdisk)"/<numberOfDisk>"$(df -h | grep data0* | wc -l)"</numberOfDisk>/g' /usr/local/vdr/etc/vdr-configuration.xml
```

Then I get: `sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to`s'`

Any inputs on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate XML documents use XML parsers/tools.

I would go with [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html).

`grep -c 'data0*'` - will output the number of matched lines, no need to pipe with `wc -l`

---

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//numberOfDisk" -v $(df -h | grep -c 'data0*') /usr/local/vdr/etc/vdr-configuration.xml > /tmp/tmp-test.xml 
           && mv /tmp/tmp-test.xml /usr/local/vdr/etc/vdr-configuration.xml
```

---

`ed` - edit mode

`-u` (`--update`) - update xml document

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Grabs all the stuff before the existing number of disks into \1, grabs the stuff after into \2.  And then prints \1 followed by the `df ...` output, followed by \2.

```
sed -e 's/\(^.*numberOfDisk>\)[0-9]*\(<.*\)/\1'$(df -h | grep -c data0)'\2/' vdr-configuration.xml
```

Another (shorter) approach

```
sed -e '/numberOf/s/[0-9]\+/'$(df -h|grep -c data0)'/' vdr-configuration.xml
```